# How can I add query parameters dymanically using gorm?

Tags: java, go, go-gorm

I am new to golang development. I have 6 parameters to pass into query using gorm. this is the select query so, based on input value we need to do filter the values. So, we need to pass the filters dynamically into query. I tried but no solution.

func GetUsers(DB *gorm.DB, Offset int, Limit int, User uibackendmodels.UserDetails) (Users []uibackendmodels.UserDetails, Err error) {

```
query := "SELECT userid, username, nickname, email, mobile, location, status, roleids, trsids, brandids, languagecode, createdat, createdby, modified, modifiedby" +
    " FROM users WHERE 1=1 "

if User.UserName != "" || User.NickName != "" {
    nameQuery := "("
    if User.UserName != "" {
        nameQuery = nameQuery + " username LIKE " + "'" + User.UserName + "%'"
    }
    if User.NickName != "" && User.UserName != "" {
        nameQuery = nameQuery + " OR nickname LIKE " + "'" + User.NickName + "%'"
    } else if User.NickName != "" {
        nameQuery = nameQuery + " nickname LIKE " + "'" + User.NickName + "%'"
    }
    query = query + " AND " + nameQuery + ")"
}

if User.BrandIDs != nil && len(User.BrandIDs) > 0 {
    brandIds := "("
    for i := range User.BrandIDs {
        if len(User.BrandIDs) == (i + 1) {
            brandIds = brandIds + "'" + User.BrandIDs[i] + "' =  ANY (brandids) "
        } else {
            brandIds = brandIds + "'" + User.BrandIDs[i] + "' =  ANY (brandids) OR "
        }
    }
    query = query + " AND " + brandIds + ")"
}

if User.TRSIDs != nil && len(User.TRSIDs) > 0 {
    trsIds := "("
    for i := range User.TRSIDs {
        if len(User.TRSIDs) == (i + 1) {
            trsIds = trsIds + "'" + User.TRSIDs[i] + "' =  ANY (trsids) "
        } else {
            trsIds = trsIds + "'" + User.TRSIDs[i] + "' =  ANY (trsids) OR "
        }
    }
    query = query + " AND " + trsIds + ")"
}
if User.RoleIDs != nil && len(User.RoleIDs) > 0 {
    roleIds := "("
    for i := range User.RoleIDs {
        if len(User.RoleIDs) == (i + 1) {
            roleIds = roleIds + strconv.FormatInt(int64(User.RoleIDs[i]), 10) + " =  ANY (roleids) "
        } else {
            roleIds = roleIds + strconv.FormatInt(int64(User.RoleIDs[i]), 10) + " =  ANY (roleids) OR "
        }
    }
    query = query + " AND " + roleIds + ")"
}
if User.Status != "" {
    query = query + " AND  status = " + "'" + EnumToString(User.Status) + "'"
}
query = query + " AND  status != 'deleted' ORDER BY modified desc LIMIT " + strconv.Itoa(Limit) + " OFFSET " + strconv.Itoa(Offset)

if err := DB.Raw(query).Scan(&Users).Error; err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return Users, nil
```

}

I need to add parameters dynamically to above query.

Answer (score 3):

In GORM, you could handle the basic inputs by enriching the Object and passing it to the function, similar to this:

```
// Would get the First user with Name="jinzhu" and Age="20"
db.Where(&User{Name: "jinzhu", Age: 20}).First(&user)
```

Whenever you cannot express a part of your statement using GORMs default functions, you can use normal SQL and Method Chaining:

```
// Would get the first User with Name="jinzhu" and id in (4,5,6,7)
ids := [4]int{4,5,6,7}
db.Where(&User{Name: "jinzhu"}).Where("id IN (?)", ids).First(&user)
```

You could also chain methods using variables

```
base := db.Where(&User{Name: "jinzhu"})
if someThing {
    base = base.Where("id IN (?)", ids) // Adding this condition just if someThing is true
}
base.First(&user) // Query your results
```

[More Information about Method Chaining](http://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html)

Comment: Hi @Alex. thank you for responding. I tried this but, it is not suited for my task. If the input parameters coming from front end, we need to pass values in query otherwise not. and I have text[] concept. in that I need to retirve the data based on in coming array.

Comment: Hi Vinodh, i added some information about method chaining using variables. This should match your case. If not, i think i did not get the problem.

Comment: I have done a method similar to this. For me, the .Where() clauses I add on a different line do not actually get put as part of the query when I call .Find()